# Vue event does not work while passing data from child to parent component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, custom-events

This is Jobs child component emitting an event to parent component.

```
<div class="card py-1 my-1" @click="$emit('active-job', job.id, job.slug)"></div>
```

Parent component accepting the event

```
<div class="col-md-4 jobs-container py-2 px-1 ml-5">
  <jobs :active-job="jobChange"></jobs>
</div>

export default {

    components: {
        FilterNavigation,
        Job,
        Jobs
    },

    data() {
        return {
            selected: false,
        }
    },

    methods: {
        jobChange(id, slug) {
            console.log(id, slug);
        }
    }
}
```

When the div was clicked, the event was emitted within child component but don't go over the parent (not logging anything).

Comment: The shorthand for an event is `@active-job`. You're using the shorthand for `v-bind`

Comment: @active-job="jobChange" , thanks by the way.

Comment: Should do, assuming everything else is okay

Answer (score 0):

You are passing prop `active-job` to child component, not listening to any events

You need to listen to event:

```html
<div class="col-md-4 jobs-container py-2 px-1 ml-5">
  <jobs @active-job="jobChange"></jobs>
</div>
```